# Checkout unstaged files from a specific folder

Tags: php, git, ubuntu

This is the status form my git

```
modified:   app/controllers/LoginController.php
modified:   app/routes.php
modified:   app/views/login.blade.php
modified:   bootstrap/start.php
modified:   public/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
modified:   public/images/screenshot.png
```

and there are many more files from the public directory. These files i don't know how got modified. May be changing permissions.

Real question is how can i `git checkout` all the files from the `public` directory so that i will only be left with my `.php` files to add them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can simply make a `git checkout public/` as refered in the documentation you can use a pathspec for checkout and it'll checkout the files in there.

`git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>`

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't make any difference. It is still showing all these file ready to be staged

Comment: I have tested it in my computer and it works fine. Perhaps the change removed the rights to write in that dir ...
you can check the changes with `git diff  public/images/screenshot.png`

Comment: can you show the result of `git status public/` and of `git checkout public/` ?

Comment: It does not show any message by `git checkout public/` after running this command i do `git status` it is still showing all those files. However one thing strange here is that those files are not even getting discarded even if i do it individually. Those files are still in my working directory to be added to staged.